# Fade Toggle not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, toggle, fade

QUESTION: Why does my fade in/fade out not fire/work? How best to resolve?

BACKSTORY: Clicking a link will trigger a javascript/jQuery event which will display or hid a series of LI's. Currently I've been able to create a link that when clicked will 'pop' a bunch of links (reveal) or hide them, but this feels kind of abrupt to me and i'm trying to make them cascade/fade in and cascade out/fade out, but my script is not working it seems. I have tried googling and looking at jsKit and jQuery websites but not found anything that I can understand well enough to properly impliment.

ACCESS EXAMPLE: Click on the white arrow icon in the little grey box in the upper right corner of the browser to reveal/open the navigation draw. Scroll down to magenta colored link which reads 'Display/Hide on click'. Clicking the magenta link ought to reveal three LIs (A), (B), and (C). Clicking the magenta link ought to hide them. However, when i click the magenta test link, nothing happens, the LI's remain 'hidden'. This is one my first attempts with JavaScript/jQuery and i'm dreadfully confused and hoping to find guidance on how to solve the issue. I am at best a hobbist when it comes to things like this, but i consider myself more of a persistent newbie.

URL: [enter link description here](http://school.max-o-matic.com/study/)

```
<!-- jQuery fadeToggle -->


 <!-- css is currently directly embedded for testing -> add to tweak.css when done
 <style media="screen" type="text/css">
    #DivB { display:none; }
 </style>

 <a href="#" onclick="fadeToggle()" id="DivA">Display/Hide on click</a>
 <div id="DivB">
      <ul>
           <li>A</li>
           <li>B</li>
           <li>C</li>
      </ul>
 </div>

<!-- function is located in scripts/jsFunctions.js -->
var fadeToggle = (function() {
   $(document).on("click",function (e) {
      if (e.target.id=="DivA") {
        $("#DivB").fadeToggle(200);
        e.stopPropagation();
        return false;
    }
    else if ($("#DivB").is(":visible")) {
      $("#DivB").fadeOut(200);
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After your script call the function `fadeToggle()`
[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/42yJt/)

Comment: Hello Sol, I've added the event/function call but the event still is not working as hoped so i must have conflict of some type maybe?

Comment: Hi Sol - I went and looked at your fiddle again, and i see that missed line 13 of the function which i've added 'fadeToggle()', but no matter how i fiddle with my files the result is still sort of faded in that the event fails to work as hoped (i.e. nothing hides or unhides as hoped)